# NetworkManager to keep trying requesting DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, lan, dhcp, networkmanager

My home router didn't have power for some time. My desktop PC is connected by an Ethernet cable to this router, with a switch in the middle. As a result of power failure, the desktop lost its DHCP lease after some time. I see in the logs that Network Manager sent 3 requests for a renewal/new lease, but then it stopped… as a result, despite that the router got power back, the desktop PC did not get internet access back till I manually restarted the connection.

How can I tell Network Manager to just keep trying requesting a DHCP lease, instead of failing after a small number of attempts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not `network manager`'s job to "guess" when the dhcp server comes back up. Network manager starts the `dhclient` program, and then relies on it to finish the process and assign the IP address. If you want it to try again and again in case of failure,  you can either restart `dhclient` on that interface or restart `network manager`. You could achieve this using a `cron` job, where if the interface cannot ping the router `network manager` is restarted. For example, you could edit `root`'s `cron` with `sudo crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`*/5 * * * * ping -c 1 -W 5 <router IP address> >/dev/null || systemctl restart network-manager`

which checks every 5 minutes whether you can ping your router's address (which most probably is the same as the `dhcp` server's address) and if not, it will restart `network manager`. `<router IP address>` will most probably be `192.168.1.1`, or something similar.